# Button setOnClickListener is not working only for one button

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

I have two different buttons in my activity, and an if statement to show them...

My if statement is working well and show the right button, but one of those buttons is not doing anything when I click on it! (Actually, it's not clickable at all!)

```
        if (isNeeded)
        {
            // buttonImportant is not clickable
            buttonImportant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("LOG", "Clicked!"); // Even this log won't work!
                    Intent intentDetailsActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                    intentDetailsActivity.putExtra("extraPosition", String.valueOf(position));
                    startActivity(intentDetailsActivity);
                }

            });

            linearLayoutImportant.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // This line is working
        }

        if (!isNeeded)
        {
            // buttonNormal is working well!
            buttonNormal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    linearLayoutNormal.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    Intent intentDetailsActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                    intentDetailsActivity.putExtra("extraPosition", String.valueOf(position));
                    startActivity(intentDetailsActivity);
                }

            });

            linearLayoutNormal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // And this one is not working too!
        }
```

The problem is, it won't return any error or log, to know what's the problem! It's log I disabled the button... (which I didn't)

I checked if it's for declarations, but everything is declared well...

I checked the XML, there's no problem there either:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutImportant"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textViewImportant"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/important"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/buttonImportant"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/details" />

</LinearLayout>

...
...

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutNormal"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/buttonClose"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textViewNormal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/normal"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/buttonNormal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/details" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### EDIT:

Here's the declarations:

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutImportant, linearLayoutNormal;
Button buttonImportant, buttonClose, buttonNormal;

...
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    linearLayoutImportant = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutImportant );

    buttonImportant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonImportant);

    buttonClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClose);
    buttonClose .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            linearLayoutNormal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });

    buttonNormal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNormal);

    linearLayoutNormal = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutNormal);
}
```

#### EDIT 2:

Alright guys, maybe I didn't made it clear...

That `isNeeded` is a variable and I control it from another place...

When I make it false, the second `if` will get executed very well, and when I make it true, the first `if` will execute too, but only the button is not clickable!

#### EDIT 3:

I also checked `.setEnabled(true);` or `.setClickable(true);`, still not working... :/

#### SOLVED:

I used the HierarchyViewer and found the problem. The problem was in XML... I had a ListView on top of second button, but it was empty, so I thought nothing's there...

Sorry everybody...

Comment: Have you added `DetailsActivity` Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: Which of the two buttons is not working for you?

Comment: you are setting only one click listener of button

Comment: show the code where you declare button in activity

Comment: may be you are giving wrong id the button in activity

Comment: place your entire activity code here

Comment: only one if condition is true where you set listener for one button other if condition is false so your listener for other button  does not set

Comment: What is the container for your 2 Linearlayouts? Are they contained in a FrameLayout? Are linearLayoutImportant and linearLayoutNormal overlapping each other?

Comment: where is this code situated ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Yes, I said the second button works well...

Comment: @George As I said in comments, buttonImportant is not working!

Comment: @VishalGaur What do you mean? Would you please explain more?

Comment: @bhargav I edited the question and added the declarations, and I triple checked for wrong ID and stuff!

Comment: @JörnBuitink It's a RelativeLayout, one of them is in the center, the other one is on top right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the HierarchyViewer and found the problem. The problem was in XML... I had a ListView on top of second button, but it was empty, so I thought nothing's there...

Sorry everybody...

Answer (score 0):

Try without the if statement in order to know if is a validation problem and you're only setting one listener

Answer (score 0):

The boolean variable `isNeeded` can take only one of the two values, either true or false. Therefore only one of the if conditions will be executed.

Since only one of the condition is true, you are only setting an `onClickListener` to one of the buttons and thus the other button won't be clickable and the log message within the `onClick` method won't be visible in the logs.

Hope this answered your question.
All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

set `isNeeded = true` before

```
if (isNeeded)
        {
            // buttonImportant is not clickable
            buttonImportant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

then test it again.
Good lucky!

Answer (score 0):

There was an error posting my ans so i have taken a screenshot of it. Please review it for your answer

[image]

Comment: It did worked, but I don't want it to perform the click itself! A button should be pressed by user... (Button is still not clickable by the way)

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah I know that.. I have commented before uplading the image that there was an issue in uploading my post with the code due to which i had to upload the image